# RAILS Can't anymore add article in my db after making somes changes (fk)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, foreign-keys

When creating a user_activities table, I added some  foreign keys, since I can not create any more activities and rails do not give me errors,
here is my code

form:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Titre (optionnel)", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :content, 'Contenu (requis)' %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, id: "wysiwyg" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :group_id, prompt: "- Choisir un groupe (requis) -", label: false, collection: current_user.groups.order('name') %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.button :submit, @activity.new_record? ? "Créer l'activité" : "Mettre à jour l'activité", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" %>
  </div>
```

Activities controller

```
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    @activity.user = current_user
    if @activity.save
      flash[:notice] = "Votre activité a été créée !"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Erreur lors la création"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:content, :title, :group_id)
  end
```

models :

```
# useractivity
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :activity }
# user
  has_many :user_activities
  has_many :activities
  has_many :activities, through: :user_activities
# Activity
  has_many :user_activities, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :users, through: :user_activities
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, presence: true
```

Trace:

```
Started POST "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-24 09:38:18 +0200
Processing by ActivitiesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"j1AMcsR16eBMf+6nTO9NN17NE7Qhz0DS07hu+w1YtYopYcwaRbQw6ThkCK3RQ0wY5MqNxM7Fe9VXezSHAZgUnw==", "activity"=>{"title"=>"TESTTITLE", "content"=>"<p>TESTCONTENT</p>", "group_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Créer l'activité"}
  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (4.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
  Group Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)
```

Controller:

```
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    @activity.user = current_user
       #line 9 ---->
    if @activity.save
      flash[:notice] = "Votre activité a été créée !"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Erreur lors la création"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: please post the errors you're getting in your logs

Comment: There's a clash here: `has_many :activities;
  has_many :activities, through: :user_activities`. You're defining the `activities` relation twice. Try renaming the first of these (you'll need to specify the `class_name`) and stick to using the `through` line. If you're only meant to be using a `has_many through` relationship, you can remove this entirely.

Comment: I have make the change, but i can't add or edit one activity :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you're defining the relationship between users and activities twice, which will cause a problem, here:

```
# user.rb
has_many :activities

# activity.rb
belongs_to :user
```

And:

```
# user.rb
has_many :user_activities
has_many :activities, through: :user_activities

# activity.rb
has_many :user_activities, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :user_activities
```

This means there's a clash when calling `user.activities` as there are two differing associations it's looking at: a `has_many - belongs to` to and a `has_many through`. The former is one to many, the latter many to many.

That's not to say this is bad practice, just that you need to ensure the naming doesn't clash. I'm not sure of the nature of the relationship and what you're looking to achieve, but something like the following would resolve this:

```
# user.rb
has_many :created_activities, class_name: 'Activity'

has_many :user_activities
has_many :activities, through: :user_activities

# activity.rb
has_many :user_activities, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :user_activities

belongs_to :master_user, class_name: 'User'
```

This updates your code to do allow you to call the following:

```
user.created_activities # has_many
user.activities # has_many through

activity.master_user # belongs_to
activity.users # has_many through
```

Obviously you can name the associations differently, and also rename the `has_many through` relationship if it adds clarity.

[The docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) here are a little weighty, but well worth spending the time to understand - there are also other options such as `foreign_key` if your column names differ from the conventions.

Hope that helps - give me a shout if you've any questions :)

Comment: Hi, thanks i just posted new answer bellow , because i can't edit my post to makes the changes :/ (sorry if i make somes inglish mistakes)

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminBarbé - looks like you're heading in the right direction. Your new trace suggests you're having a problem saving the `activity`, which is likely down to the validations or data passed to the controller. I'd suggest opening a new question specifically relating to this (feel free to @ me below it and I'll help as I can) and -- if you think this has helped -- give it a tick as answering this one :)

Comment: Alright Thanks : there the new post :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513153/rails-having-a-error-when-i-add-one-activity-in-my-db