# rails having a error when i add one activity in my DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I can not create any activities , in the log i can see the problem is on the saving function:  here is my code

Controller :

```
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    @activity.user = current_user
    if @activity.save
      flash[:notice] = "Votre activité a été créée !"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Erreur lors la création"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Form :

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Titre (optionnel)", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :content, 'Contenu (requis)' %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, id: "wysiwyg" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :group_id, prompt: "- Choisir un groupe (requis) -", label: false, collection: current_user.groups.order('name') %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.button :submit, @activity.new_record? ? "Créer l'activité" : "Mettre à jour l'activité", class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" %>
  </div>
```

error log :
I try to add this  :      puts "@activity.valid: ${@activity.valid?}\n#{@activity.errors.full_messages}"

the log return me that line : @activity.valid: ${@activity.valid?} Just before : (0.2ms) BEGIN

```
Started POST "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-24 17:21:49 +0200
Processing by ActivitiesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cq573getfK9HBo4U9xiftsdtmScb08A28AWCcwTq2+Csn7u2hmylpjMdaB5qtJ6ZfWoHV/TZ+zF0xtgPCCp69Q==", "activity"=>{"title"=>"Activity 1 ", "content"=>"<p>dzdzqdqzdqz</p>", "group_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Créer l'activité"}
  User Load (4.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
  Group Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:9
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)

#activities_controller.rb:9 =>     if @activity.save
```

There is the Controller :

```
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
    @activity.user = current_user
    if @activity.save
      flash[:notice] = "Votre activité a été créée !"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Erreur lors la création"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

There is the Activity Model:

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_activities
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :group
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

and the user Model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :created_activities, class_name: 'Activity'
  has_many :user_activities
  has_many :activities, through: :user_activities

end
```

User_activity :

```
class UserActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :activity }

end
```

The user activity table contain user_id and activity_id( when one user see one article i add that one in the table) -- Working
the creation of one actiivty still doesn't work :/

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the code of your Activity model? It looks like there might be a validation error that occurs while saving.

Comment: I agree with @Finn.  That seems most likely.  You can log the validation state just before you save in your controller to find out.  Just add: **puts "@activity.valid: ${@activity.valid?}\n#{@activity.errors.full_messages}"** before the save call, and look in your server shell output.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Finn , Post updated

Comment: @Finn , Any ideas ?

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé Does a group with ID 2 exist? If the group doesn't exist, that could be a reason for the saving to fail. 


Looks like it's failing right after the SELECT query where it's looking for the group:
`Group Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]`


But it's just a wild guess.

Comment: The group exist , already tried to change the ID   :/